# jQplot Bar grouping

Tags: jquery, jqplot

This used to work fine, but since updating to the latest version of jQplot, the bars are not grouped anymore:

I want to group two bars [space] two bars [space]. Again, this worked fine before...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     var numCompleted = [4,3,6,5,5,4,0,0,5,4,0,0,0,0];
    var numNotCompleted = [1,1,0,0,2,2,8,7,4,4,11,10,1,1];

     var dates = ['AM<br>Mon 16','PM','AM<br>Tue','PM','AM<br>Wed','PM','AM<br>Thu','PM','AM<br>Fri','PM','AM<br>Sat','PM','AM<br>Sun','PM'];

    plot3 = $.jqplot('complianceChart', [numCompleted,numNotCompleted], {
    // Tell the plot to stack the bars.
    seriesColors: [ "#81a7d4", "#d0d0d0"],
    stackSeries: true,
    shadow: false,
    //title: 'Exercises completed',
    animate: false,
    captureRightClick: false,
    grid:{drawGridLines: false, shadow : false},

    legend: {
      show: true,
      showLabels: true,
      labels: ['Completed exercises','Assigned exercises'],
     showSwatches: true,
    location: 'e',
     placement: 'outsideGrid'
    },
    seriesDefaults:{
      renderer:$.jqplot.BarRenderer,
      rendererOptions: {
          barMargin: 10,
          barPadding: 0,
          shadowOffset: 0,
          groups:7,
          highlightMouseDown: false   
      },
      pointLabels: {show: false,hideZeros: false,edgeTolerance : 10}
    },
    grid: {
            gridLineColor: '#fff',
            borderWidth:0,
            shadow: false,
            background: "white"
        },
    axes: {
      xaxis: {
          renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
          ticks: dates,
          showTickMarks: false
      },
      yaxis: {
        showTicks: false
      }
    }
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

This was a bug introduced around rev 1111.  Should be fixed now, please download the latest distribution from https://bitbucket.org/cleonello/jqplot/downloads or http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/download